# Hybrid AD Joined and Autopilot

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id, microsoft-intune

I've been working on setting up our Autopilot onboarding with our Hybrid AD.  I have managed to join a device to the domain successfully, but I have noticed some differences against when we do this manually.

1. The device shows as Azure AD Registed in Azure AD, rather than Hybrid Azure AD Joined (it was originally displaying as Azure AD Joined).  The device exists in our on-prem AD.
2. On the device itself, in Start > Settings > Accounts > Access work or school, it shows that I am connected to our "on prem AD domain", which is the same as our manually joined devices, but it also shows my Work account as connected, which is different to our manually joined devices.

Are either of these correct or have I configured something incorrectly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is right.

I would evaluate your environment to find the actual need of having devices Hybrid joined vs. just AAD joined. There are very few instances where an AD device object is needed for anything as far as users using on prem resources.

We have a hybrid domain enviornment and are moving all new devices to AAD joined only. All the domain services that are needed such as File Shares, Printing, etc are all user based not device based.  Users can access those the exact same way using a hybrid-joined device or an Azure AD only device.